# Local mail + external Office 365 Exchange account

Tags: exchange, mx-record, microsoft-office-365, mailbox

I'm not an expert at all so I'll try to explain my problem clearly.

I've a domain that I manage with cPanel.
I've also an Office 365 solution I suscribed directy on the microsoft website.
When I did the step by step procedure to get started with O365, I created all the CNAME DNS entries, add their MX and then earase the default MX (the local one) on cPanel.

But in our company, we have about 10 mailbox, but only 6 need exchange.

So I re-created the local MX and tried to change the priority to see what happened.
After doing that and read some more about how MX works on Wikipedia, I understood that It will never going to work.

So I'm wondering :

1). Is there any way to create a rule, I don't know where, to say to the server : "hey catch this e-mail, go check in the 0 priority MX (the local one) if there is a mailbox that match to deliver it and if not send it to the 5 priority MX (the O365 one) ?

2). Is someone see another solution to do that ?

Comment: While this is probably possible using a shared SMTP namespace (or Simple Domain Sharing in Office 365 parlance), I don't see why you'd want to do this. Imagine having to troubleshoot email problems in two different email systems.

Comment: I don't have an answer read, but can I ask you something? Why would you not put those 4 mailboxes to Office 365?

Comment: @Daniel - I didn't want to put those mailboxes in O365 beacause I've to suscribe for 4 new accounts and it will increase the costs. But now I realise it will be a lot more simple to manage and there is basics exchange plans I can add on O365 that doesn't cost so much for just e-mails. Also like joeqwerty and Sembee said, it will be better to keep everyone in the same environnement. However, I think it would be cool to be able to add some rules to have redirection between MX.

Comment: @Malcolm, I figured costs were a reason. Glad you realised that the most simple solution usually the best in the *long run*. Redirection between 'MX' DNS records is impossible, and would simply be not viable. Imagine the trouble a paper mail would cause, if it would be possible to write this on the envelope: 'Deliver to *address A* only if Peter opens the door. If Mark opens the door, redirect mail to *adress B*. If someone else opens the door, redirect mail to *address C*. Else, return to sender'. Poor mail deliver man :( ha ha ha

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would put everyone on to Office365. I have seen what most hosts and ISPs use for their email server and it isn't something that I would trust. Put them on the lowest email tier. 
Otherwise you would have to do some horrible kludge involving a second domain and forwarding from one to the other. However having everyone on Office365 will be a more elegant solution, with everything in the same place.

Answer (score 0):

You can put Mail Contacts in Exchange for your users without mailboxes in Office 365.  I would retain Office 365 as the **sole** MX for consistency, as well as for spam protection (EOP).  If you need to send email from the other system, make sure it's listed in your SPF record in DNS.

Also, Office 365 supports DKIM now, you could set up message signing in cPanel as well (I assume).